# Pill badges for Bootstrap v3.3.7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to apply Pill badges for Bootstrap v3.3.7?

Similar to what we have on Bootstrap 4 with the class  `.badge-pill`.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/badge/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
<span class="label label-primary">close x </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recreate a similar class increasing border-radius if such a class is not avalaible in bootstrap

```css
.label.badge-pill {
border-radius:1em;
margin:0 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>

<span class="label label-default badge-pill">default </span>

<span class="label label-primary badge-pill">primary </span>

<span class="label label-success badge-pill">success</span>

<span class="label label-info badge-pill">info </span>

<span class="label label-warning badge-pill">warning </span>

<span class="label label-danger badge-pill">danger </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a new css class :

```
.label-primary{
   border-radius: 1em;
   padding: 1em;
}
```